# How To Check Work Progress When Building A Wordpress Theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I was having a little bit of trouble with Wordpress recently, and I was wondering if someone could help.

I'm trying to build a Wordpress theme, and while I think everything is going OK, I have a little problem:

I don't know how to check my progress (i.e., view the site while it's being built).

Browsers don't read .php files and while I do have mamp, going into the localhost directory for the various php files doesn't seem to do anything either.

Also, I'm not sure which file I'd have to look at to see the site as a whole. Would it be page.php or something like that?

Basically what I'm asking is, how do I check my progress on a Wordpress site by viewing it? I mean, without zipping all the files, which is the only way I can think of to do it now, but that seems a bit time consuming if you want to change your theme a lot.

Comment: you need some way to execute the php. which means you need a WP site, since your code is basically useless without the rest of php+wp, which means you need a development server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a copy of WordPress core files on to the localhost rather than the theme folder itself.

You can download it from here https://wordpress.org/

You will also need to set up a DB on your local environment, then run through the set up. Once done, choose your theme in the admin and then you should be able to test it.

Sorry for the brief answer, I'm not completely sure if I have answered your question right.